# Unexpected NullPointerException while autoboxing / unboxing java Long type as return value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, autoboxing, scjp

Can somebody explain why the getY() method causing NullPointerException.

```
public class NullTest {
    private String s = "";

    public Long getValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public Long getX() {
        return s != null ? getValue() : new Long(0);
    }

    public Long getY() {
        return s != null ? getValue() : 0L;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NullTest nt = new NullTest();
        System.out.println("x = " + nt.getX());
        System.out.println("y = " + nt.getY());
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
x = null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullTest.getY(NullTest.java:13)
    at NullTest.main(NullTest.java:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the expression `s != null ? getValue() : 0L` is `long`, not `Long`. Therefore, if `s != null` is true and `getValue()` is `null`, a `NullPointerExcetpion` is thrown when trying to unbox that `null` to `long`.

You don't get this issue in `getX()`, since in the expression `s != null ? getValue() : new Long(0)`, both `getValue()` and `new Long(0)` are `Long`, so the type of the expression is `Long`, and no unboxing takes place.

Comment: If I replace getValue() with null in getY() no exception is thrown. Type of expression is long for this case but no exception is thrown. return s != null ? null : 0L;

Comment: @MuhammadTowfiqueImam there are different rules when one of the operands is `null`. You can see tables that summarize the rules here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25